# Springboot Jackson validation with Validated annotation not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data, jackson-databind

i have this api controller interface:

```
ResponseEntity<OkDTO> internal(@RequestBody @Validated MassPostDTO  dto  , HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception;
```

and this MassPostDTO  model:

```
@IMassValidator
public class MassPostDTO  implements Serializable { 
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Valid
    @JsonProperty(value="idSub", required=false)
    private String idSub;
    ....
```

if you see, i have @IMassValidator:

```
    @Constraint(validatedBy = MassValidator.class)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    public @interface IMassValidator {
    
        String message() default "data";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

The problem is that if i have, in my request body the attribute "idSub" declared null,
for example
{ "idSub":null,"otherVars":....... } i have a jackson error mapper:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: null; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 27] (through reference chain: MassPostDTO["idSub"])]
```

but if my request body is: { "otherVars": ....,... } the code working

What can i do for resolve?
Thank to all

Comment: Sounds like it's failing on parsing the JSON, before it ever gets to validation. It's hard to tell from the partial stack trace what the problem is exactly, but it's most likely related to the raw JSON and the DTO itself.

Comment: Hi, @Jorn thank you for the response. I have, temporaly, resolved with json property annotation with a default value that the field is forever not null. notnull annotation dont work for me and also set globally that jackson ignore not null field on deserialize, dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have annotated your controller class or interface with `@Validated` and your paramter with `@Valid` and have `spring-boot-starter-validation` in your project.
Follow below code snippet it should work.

```
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public interface OkDTO {

ResponseEntity<OkDTO> internal(@Valid @RequestBody MassPostDTO dto, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception;
}
```